# Inserir dado num banco de dados com chave estrangeira

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

estou fazendo um curso de banco e fizemos um banco de dados com varias tabelas com foreign key segue abaixo. Gostaria de saber como inserir os dados corretamente nessa tabela, pois ao inserir o carro como eu iria inserir a marca se eu ainda nao tenho ela cadastrada. O professor disse que a tabela mais forte é a do carro por isso recomendava começar a inserir por ela.

```
CREATE DATABASE PROJETO;

USE PROJETO;

CREATE TABLE CLIENTE(
    IDCLIENTE INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    NOME VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    SEXO ENUM('M','F') NOT NULL,
    ID_CARRO INT UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE TELEFONE(
    IDTELEFONE INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    NUMERO VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    TIPO ENUM('CEL','RES','COM') NOT NULL,
    ID_CARRO INT UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE MARCA(
    IDMARCA INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    MARCA VARCHAR(30) UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE CARRO(
    IDCARRO INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    MODELO VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    PLACA VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    ID_MARCAR INT UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE COR(
    IDCOR INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    COR VARCHAR(30) UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE CARRO_COR(
    ID_CARRO INT,
    ID_COR INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID_CARRO,ID_COR)
);
/* CONSTRAINTS */

ALTER TABLE TELEFONE
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_TELEFONE_CLIENTE
FOREIGN KEY(ID_CLIENTE)
REFERENCES CLIENTE(IDCLIENTE);

ALTER TABLE CLIENTE
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_CLIENTE_CARRO
FOREIGN KEY(ID_CARRO)
REFERENCES CARRO(IDCARRO);

ALTER TABLE CARRO
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_CARRO_MARCA
FOREIGN KEY(ID_MARCAR)
REFERENCES MARCA(IDMARCA);

ALTER TABLE CARRO_COR
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_COR
FOREIGN KEY(ID_COR)
REFERENCES COR(IDCOR);

ALTER TABLE CARRO_COR
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_CARRO
FOREIGN KEY(ID_CARRO)
REFERENCES CARRO(IDCARRO);

INSERT INTO CARRO VALUES(NULL,'POLO 1.6','GVO-1015',1)
INSERT INTO CARRO VALUES(NULL,'PRISMA 1.4','HCQ-4059',4)
INSERT INTO CARRO VALUES(NULL,'STRADA 1.4','OWN-1312',2)
INSERT INTO CARRO VALUES(NULL,'GRAND SIENA','GQC-1052',2)
INSERT INTO CARRO VALUES(NULL,'SAVEIRO 1.6','UWN-8963',1)
INSERT INTO CARRO VALUES(NULL,'COROLLA 2.0','DAN-0608',4)
INSERT INTO CARRO VALUES(NULL,'COROLLA XEI','BRE-8974',4)
INSERT INTO CARRO VALUES(NULL,'POLO SEDAN 1.6','ANA-1010',1)
INSERT INTO CARRO VALUES(NULL,'FIAT UNO WAY','DAI-5565',2)
INSERT INTO CARRO VALUES(NULL,'HILUX DIESEL','OWM-8956',4)

INSERT INTO CLIENTE VALUES(NULL,'DANIEL','M',2)
INSERT INTO CLIENTE VALUES(NULL,'HERALDO','M',3)
INSERT INTO CLIENTE VALUES(NULL,'BRENO','M',4)
INSERT INTO CLIENTE VALUES(NULL,'PEDRO','M',5)
INSERT INTO CLIENTE VALUES(NULL,'GERALDO','M',6)
INSERT INTO CLIENTE VALUES(NULL,'MAURA','F',7)
INSERT INTO CLIENTE VALUES(NULL,'DAIANE','F',8)
INSERT INTO CLIENTE VALUES(NULL,'MARCUS','M',9)
INSERT INTO CLIENTE VALUES(NULL,'DIOVANI','M',10)
INSERT INTO CLIENTE VALUES(NULL,'SAMIRA','F',11)

INSERT INTO MARCA VALUES(NULL,'VOLKSWAGEN')
INSERT INTO MARCA VALUES(NULL,'FIAT')
INSERT INTO MARCA VALUES(NULL,'CHEVROLET')
INSERT INTO MARCA VALUES(NULL,'TOYOTA')


INSERT INTO COR VALUES(NULL,'AMARELO')
INSERT INTO COR VALUES(NULL,'AZUL')
INSERT INTO COR VALUES(NULL,'BRANCO')
INSERT INTO COR VALUES(NULL,'LARANJA')
INSERT INTO COR VALUES(NULL,'VERMELHO')
INSERT INTO COR VALUES(NULL,'ROSA')
INSERT INTO COR VALUES(NULL,'DOURADO')
INSERT INTO COR VALUES(NULL,'VERDE')
INSERT INTO COR VALUES(NULL,'PRATA')


INSERT INTO TELEFONE VALUES(NULL,'3331-3734','CEL',2)
INSERT INTO TELEFONE VALUES(NULL,'3331-3123','COM',3)
INSERT INTO TELEFONE VALUES(NULL,'3331-1232','RES',4)
INSERT INTO TELEFONE VALUES(NULL,'3331-4566','COM',5)
INSERT INTO TELEFONE VALUES(NULL,'3331-7567','RES',6)
INSERT INTO TELEFONE VALUES(NULL,'3331-4356','COM',7);
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu não entendi porque colocou os ids como null no insert.

Se você colocou o id como null na criação da tabela não é necessário colocar valor para ele.

Eu sugiro que primeiro execute os scripts de inserção das tabelas que não tem nenhuma foreign key, conforme abaixo, assim evita erro de integridade referencial.

```
CREATE DATABASE PROJETO;

USE PROJETO;

CREATE TABLE CLIENTE(
    IDCLIENTE INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    NOME VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    SEXO ENUM('M','F') NOT NULL,
    ID_CARRO INT UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE TELEFONE(
    IDTELEFONE INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    NUMERO VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    TIPO ENUM('CEL','RES','COM') NOT NULL,
    ID_CARRO INT UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE MARCA(
    IDMARCA INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    MARCA VARCHAR(30) UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE CARRO(
    IDCARRO INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    MODELO VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    PLACA VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    ID_MARCAR INT UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE COR(
    IDCOR INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    COR VARCHAR(30) UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE CARRO_COR(
    ID_CARRO INT,
    ID_COR INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID_CARRO,ID_COR)
);
/* CONSTRAINTS */

ALTER TABLE TELEFONE
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_TELEFONE_CLIENTE
FOREIGN KEY(ID_CLIENTE)
REFERENCES CLIENTE(IDCLIENTE);

ALTER TABLE CLIENTE
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_CLIENTE_CARRO
FOREIGN KEY(ID_CARRO)
REFERENCES CARRO(IDCARRO);

ALTER TABLE CARRO
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_CARRO_MARCA
FOREIGN KEY(ID_MARCAR)
REFERENCES MARCA(IDMARCA);

ALTER TABLE CARRO_COR
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_COR
FOREIGN KEY(ID_COR)
REFERENCES COR(IDCOR);

ALTER TABLE CARRO_COR
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_CARRO
FOREIGN KEY(ID_CARRO)
REFERENCES CARRO(IDCARRO);

INSERT INTO MARCA VALUES('VOLKSWAGEN')
INSERT INTO MARCA VALUES('FIAT')
INSERT INTO MARCA VALUES('CHEVROLET')
INSERT INTO MARCA VALUES('TOYOTA')

INSERT INTO CARRO VALUES('POLO 1.6','GVO-1015',1)
INSERT INTO CARRO VALUES('PRISMA 1.4','HCQ-4059',4)
INSERT INTO CARRO VALUES('STRADA 1.4','OWN-1312',2)
INSERT INTO CARRO VALUES('GRAND SIENA','GQC-1052',2)
INSERT INTO CARRO VALUES('SAVEIRO 1.6','UWN-8963',1)
INSERT INTO CARRO VALUES('COROLLA 2.0','DAN-0608',4)
INSERT INTO CARRO VALUES('COROLLA XEI','BRE-8974',4)
INSERT INTO CARRO VALUES('POLO SEDAN 1.6','ANA-1010',1)
INSERT INTO CARRO VALUES('FIAT UNO WAY','DAI-5565',2)
INSERT INTO CARRO VALUES('HILUX DIESEL','OWM-8956',4)

INSERT INTO CLIENTE VALUES('DANIEL','M',2)
INSERT INTO CLIENTE VALUES('HERALDO','M',3)
INSERT INTO CLIENTE VALUES('BRENO','M',4)
INSERT INTO CLIENTE VALUES('PEDRO','M',5)
INSERT INTO CLIENTE VALUES('GERALDO','M',6)
INSERT INTO CLIENTE VALUES('MAURA','F',7)
INSERT INTO CLIENTE VALUES('DAIANE','F',8)
INSERT INTO CLIENTE VALUES('MARCUS','M',9)
INSERT INTO CLIENTE VALUES('DIOVANI','M',10)
INSERT INTO CLIENTE VALUES('SAMIRA','F',11)

INSERT INTO COR VALUES('AMARELO')
INSERT INTO COR VALUES('AZUL')
INSERT INTO COR VALUES('BRANCO')
INSERT INTO COR VALUES('LARANJA')
INSERT INTO COR VALUES('VERMELHO')
INSERT INTO COR VALUES('ROSA')
INSERT INTO COR VALUES('DOURADO')
INSERT INTO COR VALUES('VERDE')
INSERT INTO COR VALUES('PRATA')

INSERT INTO TELEFONE VALUES('3331-3734','CEL',2)
INSERT INTO TELEFONE VALUES('3331-3123','COM',3)
INSERT INTO TELEFONE VALUES('3331-1232','RES',4)
INSERT INTO TELEFONE VALUES('3331-4566','COM',5)
INSERT INTO TELEFONE VALUES('3331-7567','RES',6)
INSERT INTO TELEFONE VALUES('3331-4356','COM',7);
```